# PHP session Spread

Tags: php, session

I'm using `win10` + `wampserver3.0.6 x64`. And the WAMP server and PHP 7 work well together.  When I change it to `nginx` with `php7` and `wampserver3.0.6 x64`, it still works well.

When I download `php7` from official website.  And I edit the new `php.ini` according to the `php.ini` which in `wamp64.the` session can's spread!

But I find the sea the config in `php-b` is `session.auto_start = 0`! I download a `PhpStudy` for test when in different php version it work. I find they are all `set session.auto_start = 0`! Finally I just understand php in integrated package are all set `session.auto_start = 0` I feel lost~! Dose anyone can solve my doubt~!
Why did this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you have to read what have been removed and edited in php (**session.configuration**) versions

and you can see all those changes on that official php link :

http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php

after that according to **your version** you will know what you can edit in `php.ini` and what you can not

Comment: thank you ,it just session can't spread.the php.ini is default  i rename the php.ini-production.i use the wamp's php.ini  compare.this two php.ini  many config is  same.